# Do women who not follow Brahmcharya after death of husband go to hell?

Tags: death, heaven, widow, hell

Is it true that widows who don't practice celibacy after death of husbands go to hell ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was marrying brother's wife an accepted in the society of the Ramayana or pre-Ramayana era?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15560/was-marrying-brothers-wife-an-accepted-in-the-society-of-the-ramayana-or-pre-ra)

Comment: Widows can remarry. Check this question:https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15560/was-marrying-brothers-wife-an-accepted-in-the-society-of-the-ramayana-or-pre-ra

Comment: you need to give a source for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. A widow has three options after the death of her husband. Either she can follow celibacy (Vidhwavrata), can marry an other person or perform sati.

> **Naradha Smriti 12.97** “When her husband is lost or **dead**, when he has become a religious ascetic, when he is impotent, when he has been expelled from caste, in these cases a woman may be **Justified in another husband.**

> **Garuda Purana 1.107.28** “In case of disappearance or **death** or renunciation or impotent or lost caste status of her husband, in these five cases **a woman is allowed to take another husband.”**

> **Agni Purana 154.4-7** “Women are allowed to have another husband in the following five adversaries;- (the first husband) is lost, **dead**, has become an ascetic, impotent or fallen morally. If the husband is dead, she should be given to the brother of the deceased. In the absence of brother, **she should be given to anyone as one wished”**

Comment: i don't think the english translation can be accepted on such an important matter. the word 'Pati' means protector. Raghu-Pati is name of sri rama, does it mean he is husband of raghu ? There is Manu Smriti verse that says 'only 1 time kanya daan is done'.

Comment: @mar I am ready for a debate in this matter. I have checked all the translations. And even Parashara Smriti 4.28 says that a women can be remarried.

Comment: @mar you can read my blog too https://vedicanubhav.blogspot.com/2021/02/exposing-lies-on-sati.html?m=1

Comment: can u post original Sanskrit verse ?